# Calculating base resistor for transistor

Tags: arduino, transistors, resistors

I'm building an LED driver from 2SD600 transistors and an Arduino Nano(clone) but I'm quite new to transistors and have no idea how to calculate the base resistor nor what info I need for it.

I'm switching a ~5m 12V RGB strip that needs around 800mA/color to work.  I'm turning the transistor on from the Arduino Nano's digital output that can supply 5V and 20mA continuously, maximum 40mA.

The digital outputs are handled by an ATmega328p, current source for my choice of outputs (D5, D6 and D7) is <150mA and current sink is <100mA.

It is either fully on or going from 0% to 100% linearly slowly.

[image: Here is the schematic, not using 2N2369.]

Comment: Well, 800 mA / 20 mA sounds in the right ballpark. How is the device with that digital output powered, what is the voltage specification sourcing or sinking 20 mA? How frequently do you plan to switch current on and off?

Comment: @greybeard it is either going to be on all the time or by going thro all the colors in "rainbow effect" aka fading it, not sure about the fade speed yet. Arduino is powered by 2A step down converter set at 5V from the same 12V 8A source, 20mA seems to be a max continuous current based on their website info.

Comment: What transistor are you using? The complete part number, please. As far as I can tell "D600" is not an actual transistor part number.

Comment: Draw a schematic please.

Comment: (\$V_{OL}\$ at 20 mA specified at \$V_{CC}\$ 5 V only: 0.9 V, \$V_{OH}\$ 4.2 V (\$V_{CC}\$ - .8 V)(!). For all I can tell, \$V_{BE}\$ should be between .9 and 1 V.)

Comment: Well, the output shall not be overloaded - it won't be at \$V_{CC}\$ - \$V_{BE}\$, about 4.2 V, divided by 20 mA - round up to next E6 value. But a 2SD600 is already desaturating with a  \$V_{CE}\$ of about 1.2 V at 20/800 mA, dissipating about 1 Watt, max in free air getting real hot. 2N2369 is spec'ed at 200 mA to begin with…

Comment: (A contemporary logic-level MOSFET should do much better.)

Comment: @greybeard There was no option for 2SD600 so I had to use 2N2369 to draw that, I have a heatsink on a 2SD600 so no worries there don't have any logic level fets atm but might make a new circuit later on, so 220ohm should be good right?,

Comment: What is D5, D6 and D7?

Comment: @Andyaka digital outputs

Comment: Well, let's check: 4.2 V - 1 V / 220 Ohm is about 14.5 mA min. base current - at 25°C, \$V_{CE}\$ would be more like 1.7 V. Less at 70°… I think it's pushing it where there are better alternatives.

Comment: To fully turn on the 2SD600 the base current needed will be about 80 mA and this won't happen even with a 0 ohm base resistor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [2SD600](https://www.el-component.com/bipolar-transistors/2sd600) NPN has a minimum gain of 60. That means that, for 0.8 A out, you need a base current of at least 13 mA. That's near the maximum current for the GPIO of a megaAVR  (16 mA) and, in any case, the GPIO will suffer significant voltage drop at such a current.

You *could* try using 100 Ohm resistors in series with the base. That might kind-of work. But, from an engineering standpoint, a recommend one of these sound solutions:

- Use MOSFETs instead of BJTs
- Add a buffer IC between the megaAVR  and the base resistors that can drive a higher current without significant voltage drop
- Add a small NPN BJT (2N3904) between the megaAVR  and the base resistors to amplify the current

Comment: `minimum gain of 60` @ \$I_C\$ 50 mA, \$V_{CE}\$ 5 V. At 500 mA, it's already down to 20 - but you'd want it *saturated* at 800 mA. Darlington looks an outdated alternative.

Comment: Thank you, I will get myself some some logic level FETs.

Comment: I did not suggest Darlingtons because of their high voltage drop, which would be unacceptable in this application.